# Owner Search for given Server SNO

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, python

I am newbie to NLP.
I have a excel sheet with following columns: 
    Server_SNo, 
    Owner, 
    Hosting Dept, 
    Bus owner, 
    Applications hosted, 
    Functionality,
    comments

a. Except the Server_SNo, other columns may or may not have data.
b. For some records there is no data except Server_SNo which is the first column.
c. One business owner can own more than 1 Server.

So, out of 4000 records, about 50% of data contain direct mapping for a server with owner.  Remaining 50% of data have combination of other columns (Owner, Hosting Dept, Bus owner, Applications hosted, Functionality and comments)

Here is my problem, I need to find the owner for the given Server_Sno for 50% of data which have combination of other columns (Owner, Hosting Dept, Bus owner, Applications hosted, Functionality and comments).

I have just started to build the code using Python and NLTK.

Is this an NLP problem? Am I going in right direction using Python and NLTK for NLP?

Any insights is appreciated.

-Mani

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this classify as an NLP problem, there is almost no semantic analysis needed, it is more like a classification problem using categorical features.

NLTK is surely valuable if you want to perform some text 'cleaning' or preprocessing before encoding the variables. The only NLP application that I think you could apply here is some sentiment analysis on the comments to extract extra features (like a number expressing the negativeness or positiveness of each comment). Nevertheless you might want to do that using some pre-trained models cause your dataset is pretty small.

Comment: Hello Eodardo,  Thanks for your reply, I was able to do this in python using dataframe itself.  I am currently adding some more enhancements to it.  I will post the completed code sometime soon.